# Adding more than one property to a GUI built with Qt Designer causes SystemError in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

So I just discovered something which I believe is a bug, but maybe I did something wrong so thought I should post it here.

I designed a GUI using **Qt Designer** and then loaded that into my interface class using `loadUi()`. All of that works without any problems. However, then, I added properties to my class: A single property doesn't cause any issues, but as soon as there is more than one, I receive a `SystemError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 23, in <module>
    GUI = MainWindow()
  File "test.py", line 9, in __init__
    loadUi('../gui/test.ui', self)
  File "..\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\__init__.py", line 226, in loadUi
    return DynamicUILoader(package).loadUi(uifile, baseinstance, resource_suffix)
  File "..\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\Loader\loader.py", line 72, in loadUi
    return self.parse(filename, resource_suffix, basedir)
  File "..\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 1021, in parse
    actor(elem)
  File "..\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 942, in createConnections
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self.toplevelWidget)
SystemError: <built-in function connectSlotsByName> returned a result with an error set
```

The UI that I loaded in this case is a plain QDialog template, nothing else. You can see the contents of `test.ui` below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Here is the code that created the error:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        loadUi('../gui/test.ui', self)
        self.test = 1

    @property
    def test2(self):
        return self.test

    @property
    def test3(self):
        return self.test


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = MainWindow()
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

As soon as you remove one of the properties or the `loadUi()` command, it works again. What is wrong?

Comment: Do you by any chance run PyQt 5.12 and/or Python 3.7? Because it seems to be a bug in PyQt that was fixed about a year ago. If that's the case, try to update to version 5.13.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that! What I also didn't know is that I am using PyQt 5.9.2, because apparently, using Anaconda, that is the version that is being deployed by default for some reason: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pyqt I only installed my distribution a few months ago and of course assumed that the packages would be up-to-date.

Comment: There is also a newer versiona available via anaconda, I am not sure why this is not the default: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyqt, however, that is still version 5.12 so this bug would still be there.

Comment: I updated to version 5.14.1 now using `pip install PyQt5` and this bug is no longer an issue.

Comment: Good to know. I just realized that I have almost the same versions on another computer (PyQt5.12.3 and Python 3.7.5) and can confirm the issue for that combination. In case you were wondering, this is the thread in the PyQt mailing list: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2019-August/042003.html

Comment: I was trying to solve an issue and ended up here. I run your code and got a strange result: it runs fine in the python interpreter (`python main.py`) but gives an error only when "debugging" (I'm using VS Code). Besides, it gives me a different error (`AttributeError`). The error is caused because it tries to execute the `@property` methods before creating the attribute `self.test`. By moving the line `self.test = 1` to above the `loadUi`, the `AttributeError` does not happen. So, I'd like to ask: do you know why the `loadUi` tries to run the `@property` methods? Is that related to the bug?